# QED - as three letters - to the right of a display equation

Tags: symbols, equations, amsthm

What is the best way for me to get "QED"--as the three letters, not the square generated by `\qed`--flush with the right side of a page on the same line as a display equation?

Note - I am intentionally not using the `proof` environment.

Comment: `\text{QED} after the equation should work. To do it often, try `\renewcommand{\qed}{\text{QED}}`, then use \qed.

Comment: @EthanBolker Doesn't that produce the text immediately to the right of the equation, as opposed to flush right (see my edit to the question)?

Comment: does `\tag{QED}` work as you would like?

Comment: Is this for an displayed expression produced by `equation*` or for other environments as well?

Comment: @cmhughes No, I do not want the parentheses around the "QED"

Comment: @GonzaloMedina For `equation*` environment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since this is only for the `equation*` environment, one can use `\displaymath@qed` (defined by `amsthm`); in the following example I `\let` the command `\QED` to be `\displaymath@qed` and used the `etoolbox` package to redefine `\qedsymbol` inside `equation*` to produce the text "Q.E.D." in small caps and using `\footnotesize`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\let\QED\displaymath@qed
\makeatother
\AtBeginEnvironment{equation*}{\renewcommand\qedsymbol{{\footnotesize\textsc{q.\,e.\,d.}}}}

\begin{document}

some test text goes here test text goes here test text goes here test text goes here test text goes here test text goes here test text goes here  test text goes here
\begin{equation*}
a=b + c.\QED
\end{equation*}
some test text goes here test text goes here test text goes here test text goes here test text goes here test text goes here test text goes here  test text goes here

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A very simple solution, using the `\tag*` command from the `mathtools` package. It also works for groups of equations:

```
    \documentclass[12pt,a4paper,bothsides]{article}

    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
    \usepackage{fourier} 
    \usepackage{mathtools}

    \newcommand*\QED{\tag*{\scshape q.\:e.\:d.}}

    \begin{document}

    \[ a²  = b²  + c²  \QED \]%

    \begin{align}
      a²  & = b²  + c² \\
      a³    & \neq b³  + c³ \QED
    \end{align}

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Since you mention the square generated by `\qed`, I'll assume that you are using the `amsthm` package or something that loads it automatically. Now, the square is not the `\qed` itself, it is the `\qedsymbol`. What `\qed` does is to print the `\qedsymbol` with some space to the left and other bells and whistles so that it does not overprint a rather full line. So you can redefine `\qedsymbol` like
    `\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{\mbox{\textsc{q.\,e.\,d.}}}`
or something similar (that's Q.E.D. in small capitals, letterspaced, as was used in the old high school geometry books). Or you can use instead
    `\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{\mathrm{QED}}`
if that is what you want. Then, invoking `\qed` inside an unnumbered display
will produce the desired result, flush right. If your proof ends with a displayed equation, use `\qedhere` inside the display, so that `\end{proof}` does not generate another end-proof marker sitting alone on an extra line.

Comment: Did you try your proposed solution? In its present form, i.e., just using `\qed` with no extra work, the symbol won't be flushed to the right.